# Sort Array first by including ID in other Array, second by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

```
const linkedProjects = ["2", "3"];
const projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Project 1",
    lastUpdate: 1575976301091
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Project 2",
    lastUpdate: 1575975812091
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Project 3",
    lastUpdate: 1575976378391
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Project 4",
    lastUpdate: 15753276301091
  }
];
```

What I want to achieve:

I want to sort my Array `projects` which has multiple objects.

First it should order objects first which are included in `linkedProjects` by ID.

Second it should order the remaining objects by `lastUpdate`.

What I have done so far:

```
projects.sort((a, b) => {
    const [dateA, dateB] = [
        a.lastUpdate && a.lastUpdate.getTime(),
        b.lastUpdate && b.lastUpdate.getTime()
    ];
    if (linkedProjects && linkedProjects.length > 0) {
      if (linkedProjects.includes(a.id)) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    }
    if (dateA === dateB) {
        console.log("0a")
        return 0;
    }
    if (!dateA) {
      console.log("1b")
        return 1;
    }
    if (!dateB) {
        console.log("-1b")
        return -1;
    }
    if (dateA > dateB) {
        console.log("-1d")
        return -1;
    }
    if (dateA < dateB) {
        console.log("1")
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
})
```

Sorting by lastUpdate works and was implemented before, but my new implementation with `linkedProjects` does not work.

Outcome should be:

```
[
  {
    id: 2, // included in linkedProjects
    name: "Project 2",
    lastUpdate: 1575975812091
  },
  {
    id: 3, // included in linkedProjects
    name: "Project 3",
    lastUpdate: 1575976378391
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Project 4",
    lastUpdate: 15753276301091 // is newer than Project 1
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Project 1",
    lastUpdate: 1575976301091 // is older than Project 4
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put first the linked, then sort the remind by `lastUpdate`

```js
const linkedProjects = ["2", "3"];
const projects = [{id: 1,name: "Project 1",lastUpdate: 1575976301091},{id: 2,name: "Project 2",lastUpdate: 1575975812091},{id: 3,name: "Project 3",lastUpdate: 1575976378391},{id: 4,name: "Project 4",lastUpdate: 15753276301091}];

const sorted = projects.sort(function(a,b){
  if(linkedProjects.indexOf(''+a.id) !== -1) return -1;
  if(linkedProjects.indexOf(''+b.id) !== -1) return 1;
  return b.lastUpdate - a.lastUpdate
});
console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a function which returns either the order of the projects or a large number and sort by this delta or tyke the delta of the last update.

```js
const
    linkedProjects = [2, 3],
    getOrder = ({ id }) => (linkedProjects.indexOf(id) + 1) || Number.MAX_VALUE,
    projects = [{ id: 1, name: "Project 1", lastUpdate: 1575976301091 }, { id: 2, name: "Project 2", lastUpdate: 1575975812091 }, { id: 3, name: "Project 3", lastUpdate: 1575976378391 }, { id: 4, name: "Project 4", lastUpdate: 15753276301091 }];

projects.sort((a, b) => getOrder(a) - getOrder(b) || b.lastUpdate - a.lastUpdate);

console.log(projects);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```